# Add a spacing in the WooCommerce price listing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to figure out how to add a spacing between the regular price and the sales price in WooCommerce but sadly without any luck so far

```
    <?php 
    $valuta = getCurrency();
    $price = $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $product->get_price_html());
    if($value != 'USD'){
        $price = convertCurrency($price, 'USD', $valuta, '&nbsp;');
    }
?>
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="product_price headerfont"><?php echo $price; ?> <?php echo getCurrency(true); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And this is the result

```
<span class="product_price headerfont">85.0059.50 USD</span>
```

Any help or pointers are much appreciated

Comment: `if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() )` is supposed to use `==`, I guess?

Comment: thanks but sadly no, if i place `==` the prices are not showing at all

Comment: Just saw this: `if($value != 'USD')` Is that correct or is it supposed to say `$valuta`?

Comment: it's correct, i am reediting an existing page

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2);
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $is_var = $product->is_type('variable');
    $regular_price = floatval($is_var ? $product->get_variation_regular_price("min") : $product->get_regular_price());
    $sale_price = floatval($is_var ? $product->get_variation_sale_price("min") : $product->get_sale_price());
    $final = "<span class='amount'>" . sprintf("€%.2f / $%.2f", $sale_price, $sale_price * $conv) . "</span>";
    if ($regular_price > $sale_price) {
        $regular = "<span class='amount'>" . sprintf("€%.2f / $%.2f", $regular_price, $regular_price * $conv) . "</span>";
        $final = "<del>$regular</del><br/><ins>$final</ins>";
    }
    return $final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing the following

`<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>`

`<span class="product_price headerfont"><?php echo str_replace(get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), "", $price); ?> <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></span>`

`<?php endif; ?>`